# How to replace square brackets with a space using tr?

Tags: bash, tr

Using the "tr -c" command. I essentially need to replace square brackets ([,]) with white space (' ') and have only come to solutions using sed. Is it possible with translate?

Comment: kindly post sample Input_file here in code tags.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
tr '[]' ' ' < file
```

The option `-c` is not helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to replace the square brackets you can use something like this:

```
 $: tr '[]' ' ' < inputfile
```

This will return your input file with spaces instead of brackets. Not sure why you are using `tr -c` if regular `tr` would suffice.

Useful link here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/12/linux-tr-command/

Comment: This won't replace the square brackets with a space.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't have my glasses on last night. I will modify it.